# Wordpress not adding images at all

Tags: wordpress, image, upload

I have a problem with Wordpress image adding.

When I try to upload image on some WP Page and get an error like this:

mysite.com/wp-admin/%7B%7B%7B%20attachment.sizes.full.url%20%7D%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)

It seems that for some reason Wordpress is saving my images like this:
mysite.com/wp-admin/%7B%7B%7B%20attachment.sizes.full.url%20%7D%7D%7D
and when I open it, it appears broken (of course).

I am not a WP developer, so I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Is there anyone who could help me with this please...???

Thank you

Comment: how are you uploading your images (like, from a file on your computer, or someplace else)? Or, what is the name of the image you are trying to upload(file name before you upload it) ?

Comment: I upload is like this: I login to wordpress, open a page in on the right side i have a title Background image and under that I have a button that I press on and I get to window where I select my image. And when I select it, I get this:    <# _.each( attachments, function( attachment ) { #> <# } ); #> <# _.each( attachments, function( attachment ) { #> <# } ); #> <# _.each( attachments, function( attachment ) { #> <# if ( attachment.sizes.hasOwnProperty( 'thumbnail' ) ) { #>  and that is it.

Comment: I upload it from a computer and file name is "elit31.png"